# User profiles get replicated on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, new-users

I was looking at Stack Overflow users under [users -> new users](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=newusers)

One user profile is being replicated named *Shubham Verma*. It is guaranteed not two different users with exact same name and profile picture (also reputations).

Will be available if further assistance required.

[image: Screenshot of the web page having issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, no bug here, at least not in this level.

This is actual person creating new accounts in order to bypass a [suspension](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7325701/shubham-verma).

The mess we see (e.g. the high reputation without any activity) is probably the result of half-baked auto merge, since the user is using the same credentials, but those are still different accounts.

We need to keep watch on those new accounts, and flag any new post they make, asking the moderators to delete the account.

This also should lead to longer suspension on the main account as a punishment.

Comment: So it's not a bug, what to do now, do I delete the question or something?(new to meta, not sure how this works). Also I don't understand, how can someone bypass a suspension, or use same credentials for different accounts (Want to know for curiosity purpose :p)

Comment: No, don't delete the question here. As for creating the accounts, the system *should* detect this, but from what I saw over the years this detection is very lacking and the auto merge fails a lot, which is most likely the case here as well, maybe as result of the suspension.

Comment: While plausible, this user has never had any account merges and I honestly have no idea how they managed to create additional Stack Overflow profiles attached to the same network account. We'll look into it.

Comment: @animuson I also tried creating new account using same credentials, ended up just logging into my existing account. Maybe being suspended breaks this process?

Comment: @animuson hey, did you have a chance to look into this?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I didn't personally, but it looks like a dev cleaned up all the profiles (they'd managed to create 5 additional ones all linked to the same network account) and fixed whatever bug was there.

Comment: @animuson thanks, but did you/they figure how he managed to do that? Maybe the actual bug he was exploiting wasn't fixed in its "core" yet, i.e. others might also do that. :/